# Phonegap Photoswipe how to load external folder to show images

Tags: cordova, hyperlink, directory, external, photoswipe

I'm using Phonegap for my new android/ios app. 
I'm also using the photoswipe plugin.

When my app is online in the store, I can't edit the pictures anymore if you load local urls... Is there a way to load an external folder to show my pictures.. So when I want to add a picture i just upload it to the online folder?

I'm a n00b with javascript and html, so can someone please help me, and explain it the easy way?